# Eliminate redundant constraints using Google OR-Tools

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, or-tools

I'm using `OR-Tools` to solve simple LP problem. As the input to the problem I have for example 10 linear equations. If I feed them to the algorithm, problem will be solved. I can remove 7 of those 10 linear equations I use as an input, and still get the same solution - meaning 7 of 10 are redundant.

Is there some API in Google's `OR-Tools` that will flag which equations are redundant? I would like to find core set of equalities that is sufficient to solve the LP problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already asked in the [OR-Tools mailing list](https://github.com/google/or-tools/discussions/3926#discussioncomment-7065399).

No good answer. I suggest looking at the literature on LP presolve.